# What different types can social network users on platforms such as Facebook, Reddit, and 9gag be categorized into?

Tags: user-behavior, social-network

Bartle [categorized videogamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartle_taxonomy_of_player_types) into 4 different types based on user preferences and character theory: Socializers, Explorers, Killers, Achievers. Is there/can there be a similar classification for Social Network users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper [Design Lessons from the Fastest Q&A Site in the West](http://bid.berkeley.edu/files/papers/mamykina-stackoverflow-chi2011.pdf) categorises users into two segments:

- Asking / Answering (Posting) Behaviour - so determining their preference for Asking, Answering, Reading Only, Asking & Answering, Posting pictures etc.
- Their Level of Participation in the community. Meaning, how often they come into the community and do one of the 4 activities mentioned above.

The paper distinguishes four answer behaviours:

1. Community Activists - who post regularly/daily over a number of months.
2. Shooting Stars - who come and are very active for a short burst and then are less active. So they might be passionate about one topic and engage for a few hours and then not be seen again for a month or so.
3. Low Profile Users - those with intermittent and infrequent activity levels.
4. Lurkers / Visitors - those who read but never post or vote or comment.

I have read that in some social media platforms, the Lurkers are the most active, meaning, they represent the largest segment but I don't have stats to back this up.